# How to exclude folders when using TFS in vscode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, tfvc

I am using Visual Studio Team Services extension in VS code for check in. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.team

I am now trying to check in change in angular project, but I am annoyed by excluded 16000 files which are from node_modules:
[image]

How can I exclude those files from source control? In Visual Studio I used .tfignore file, how about vscode?

Comment: TFVC appears to support a [`.tfignore` file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155786.aspx#Anchor_1) that might work here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder

Comment: @dbdark Not Git, but TFVC.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem creating a dotnet core 2 cli react project using visual studio code and TFVC. I created a .tfignore file in the root (same place as the .gitignore).

Then I copied the content in the .gitignore file into .tfignore file, save and done...

Comment: To expand on this, within the `.tfignore` file, you need to add the following entry: `\node_modules`

Comment: I'm not using git, nor do I have a .gitignore file. I'm using TFVC, and I've deposited a .tfignore file in the root of my folder, along side a single file I hope to ignore: firmware.bin. The .tfigore file seems to be ignored, and firmware.bin still shows in the "Excluded Changes" group in source control. Any ideas?

Comment: Note: the .gitignore file is created by the angular cli. It doesn't mean you selected the wrong option when connecting to your source control. I just copied the file over directly and it seemed to work - I don't believe any conversion is required.

Answer (score 1):

So I followed everything that the others mentioned, but was missing the following, for **.tfignore** to skip the files:

Place the following in you Visual Studio Code's **settings.json** file.

```
"tfvc.restrictWorkspace": true
```

**settings.json** location:

File - Preferences - Settings (top right-hand corner(Open Settings (JSON)))

That I found the answer [here](https://rasor.github.io/using-tfs-from-vscode.html).